# Purpose of Underscore method in Buildr

Tags: ruby, buildr

Can anyone explain the purpose of the "_" (underscore) in the following code? Thanks.

`package(:zip).include _('target/docs/*')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Buildr, the [underscore method is an alias to the `path_to` method](http://buildr.apache.org/rdoc/classes/Buildr/Project.html#M000201):

```
_('foo', 'bar')
# => foo/bar
_('/tmp')
# => /tmp
_(:base_dir, 'foo')
# => /home/project1/foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and examples.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a method that Buildr defines. You may need to hunt around and find it in the gem source. It's probably a helper method that expands that path specification.